# how to fit background image particular size without cut image size

Tags: css

I have a background image in the following div, but the image gets cut off

Is there a way to show the background image without cutting it off?

Comment: No, unless you show us the code...

Comment: background-size: contain

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty easy fix.  Most of it comes down to using percents to specify the size of the image rather than pixels.

```
div {
    background: url(img.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `background-size: cover;` property to get the image centered, though what you are trying to achieve will be always impossible except in case the dimensions of the background image matches perfectly the dimensions of the container div; otherwise, it will always result in a distorted image. I guess `background-size: cover;` is the most approximate.

```css
.contain_img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/200/300?image=1082);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain_img"></div>
```